# CMSensorRecord Processing Large List Troubles?

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch, ios9, core-motion, watchos-2

I am using the new CMSensorRecord with watchOS 2 and have no problems up until I try to get data out of CMRecordedAccelerometerData. I believe I am using fast enumeration like it is reccomended to go through the list from the docs

```
  for (CMRecordedAccelerometerData* data in list) {  

      NSLog(@"Sample: (%f),(%f),(%f) ", data.acceleration.x,data.acceleration.y,data.acceleration.z);        

    }
```

however going through even 60 min of data takes a long time process (the accelerometer records at 50Hz (50 data points a second)) — the WWDC video on Core Motion recommends to *decimate* the data to decrease processing time, how can this be implemented? Or am I misunderstanding the intention of using this, are we intended to send the CMSensorDataList to the iPhone for processing? I would like to add each axis to an array on the Apple Watch without iPhone help. 
If for example I recorded for the max 12 hours — there would be over 100 million data points to read over, even in this case would it be possible for the Apple Watch to read through this?

At the moment it is taking minutes to read through a couple million data points.

Comment: (Closed) - The logging tasked the CPU...